# In Claws-mail, how to put the signature above quoted text in a reply

Tags: signature, claws

In Lubuntu 20.04.1, I'm using Claws Mail 3.17.5   I'd like to be able to click reply and have the cursor position at the top of my message with my signature followed by the quoted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to `Configuration > Preferences > Compose > Templates > Reply`

and change your reply template to

```
%cursor
%as
%N wrote:
%Q
```

That will put the cursor for replys at the top, below that the signature and then the quoted original mail.